# Does `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` always delete the data? Or only when there is an RealmMigrationNeededException?

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#opening-realms
The realm documentation says

```
deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: delete the Realm if migration is needed; this is useful under development since the data model might change often
```

In the `RealmConfiguration.java`, it says

```
 * Setting this will change the behavior of how migration exceptions are handled. Instead of throwing a
 * {@link io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException} the on-disc Realm will be cleared and recreated
 * with the new Realm schema.
```

So my question is, does `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` always delete the database when there is a migration? Or does it only delete it when the migration failed?

Comment: It's will deleted schema when you changed your realm classes structure.

Comment: @RajasekaranM Thanks. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` will deleted app schema when you changed your realm classes structure. otherwise it's wont delete your schema.